# How can I group by a case column than uses a JSON object?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've tried the following

```
select payload:col1 as col1
       , case
            when contains(payload:col2, 'aaa') then 'type1'
            else 'other'
         end as type
       , count(*) as c
  from table1
  group by col1, type
  ;
```

where `payload` is a JSON/object column.

This results in a `SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 26 'table1.PAYLOAD' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.`

As far I understand I should be able to group by the case column `type` and `payload` is not really in any output column (there is case that uses `payload` but `payload` itself is not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SELECT list of a `GROUP BY` query you can reference "anything" ***inside*** an aggregation expression, but only expressions from the `GROUP BY` list ***outside*** an aggregation expression.

In your case, I believe (untested) that you should not have gotten an error if the `GROUP BY` contained `payload:col2` or `contains(payload:col2, 'aaa')` or the whole "type" column expression.  Only the last two would give a correct result, however...

The most compact `GROUP BY` expression that will work I think will be:

```
GROUP BY col1, type, contains(payload:col2, 'aaa')
```

With that your `SELECT list` expressions only references `GROUP BY` expressions from the table expression of the query.

EDIT: Too low reputation to comment );

@[ecerulm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90580/ecerulm) No, I meant the whole "type" ***column expression***, ie:

```js
GROUP BY col1, type,
     case
        when contains(payload:col2, 'aaa') then 'type1'
        else 'other'
     end
```

In fact it is explained exactly how this should work in the SQL standard, so the error message you receive is according to standard.

Comment: So `GROUP BY type` should work, is that what you say? I already created a support ticket towards snowflake about this Case#00071297

Comment: I don't know about the SQL standard in general but in this particular case for Snowflake it's legal. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58268888/90580). You can `GROUP BY type` where type refers to the  `case when payload:col2 ... end` in the select clause. I does work in the the example table I provide in my answer, but I still get the error in my "real" table.

Comment: I tried using the *type* from the SELECT list in your example and it worked on Snowflake, but eg. on Oracle I got "invalid identifier".  The standard disallows it, but it is kind of convenient.  And if you have *type* as a column in the query table expression, there is no way to name the *type* in the SELECT list.  I understand why you reported it as a bug, as it is not consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the cause is that **there is a column with the same name in the source table**. In your case if there is a `table1.type`  then the `GROUP BY type` with refer to `table1.type` and not your `CASE....END as type`.

In the regular case you can refer to the `CASE ... END as colname` in the `GROUP BY` clause by alias, without having to repeat the `CASE...END` in the `GROUP BY`. For example the following self-contained examples runs with no problems:

```
create or replace temporary table table1 as (
    select parse_json(column1) as payload from values
         ('{"col1": 1, "col2": "aaa"}')
        ,('{"col1": 1, "col2": "aaa"}')
        ,('{"col1": 2, "col2": "aaa"}')
        ,('{"col1": 2, "col2": "bbb"}')
);
select
    payload:col1 as col1
    ,case
     when payload:col2 = 'aaa' then 'type1'
     else 'other'
    end as type
    ,count(*) as c
from table1
group by col1, type;

-- result:
COL1    TYPE    C
1   type1   2
2   type1   1
2   other   1
```

That shows that you can `GROUP BY xxx` where `xxx` is an alias of case column that uses the colon operator on a JSON object.

Also you can always use a CTE as workaround:

```
with t1 as (
  select payload:col1 as col1
       , case
            when contains(payload:col2, 'aaa') then 'type1'
            else 'other'
         end as type
  from table1
)
select col1
       ,type
       ,count(*) as c 
  group by col1, type
  ;
```

In this case if there is a `table.type` that is not visible in the last select so the `group by type` refers to `t1.type` and not `table1.type`.